# string or binary data would be truncated

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, binary

I had web page where I add update to data in it it worked well later and when I add data today I had this error string or binary data would be truncated ..... although I tested that on other PC and this error didnot apear again so what the a problem.

Answer (score 2):

That's the error message you get, if you attempt to enter data that is longer than the underlying 'backing' column in a database.

[It seems likely you entered different data on the two PC's you tested on]

Answer (score 1):

You get an error like this if you try to put a too long string in a database column, like "abcd" in varchar(3).